# Panel data with multiple dimensions

Tags: r, regression, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

Given my fake data

```
A tibble: 20 x 5
   State Period Region     y     x
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1      1 A          6     3
 2     1      2 A          6     3
 3     1      3 A          0     2
 4     1      4 A          0     3
 5     1      5 A         10     0
 6     2      1 A          4     0
 7     2      2 A          3     3
 8     2      3 A          5     0
 9     2      4 A          5     4
10     2      5 A          7     0
11     3      1 B          0     5
12     3      2 B          2     4
13     3      3 B          4     0
14     3      4 B          7     3
15     3      5 B          7     2
16     4      1 B          3     3
17     4      2 B          5     1
18     4      3 B         10     0
19     4      4 B          9     4
20     4      5 B          2     1
```

States 1 and 2 are in region A and states 3 and 4 are in region b.

I wish to see the difference between being in region A and region B.

```
library(plm)

reg1 <- plm(y ~ x, data = fakeData, model = "within", effect = "twoways", index = c("State", "Period"))

reg2 <- plm(y ~ x + factor(Region), data = fakeData, model = "within", effect = "twoways", index = c("State", "Period"))
```

While this piece of code generates the same results from `reg1` and `reg2`.

```
Twoways effects Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = y ~ x, data = fakeData, effect = "twoways", 
    model = "within", index = c("State", "Period"))

Balanced Panel: n = 4, T = 5, N = 20

Residuals:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-5.508730 -1.194643  0.066667  1.899603  3.965873 

Coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)
x -0.93651    0.79599 -1.1765   0.2642

Total Sum of Squares:    148.3
Residual Sum of Squares: 131.72
R-Squared:      0.11177
Adj. R-Squared: -0.53421
F-statistic: 1.38425 on 1 and 11 DF, p-value: 0.26421
```

Why does this happen and how should I get the regional effect?

Comment: You might want to look at the nested random effect model as in "Baltagi BH, Song SH, Jung BC (2001). “The unbalanced nested error component regression model.” Journal of Econometrics, 101, 357-381." It is implemented in `plm()` with effect = "nested" (see example code in `?plm`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first regression, you're regressing `y` on `x` and including state *and* period fixed effects. This is, in essence, a two-way fixed effects equation. The state fixed effects remove all time-invariant heterogeneity across states. But let's think about this intuitively. What's a time-constant attribute of a state? For instance, some aspects of your panel unit don't change much over time, or at least they change very slowly. For instance, time-constant attributes may include a state's topographical features, its land area, and even its geographic positioning within the country. Say I know the State of Texas is in my sample. Well, one aspect of a state that's *fixed* is its regional positioning. Thus, if Texas is in my sample, then I know it's located in the South-Central region of the United States. The state fixed effects fully absorb the `Region` variable as a consequence.

First, let's use `lm()` with state *and* period fixed effects. I used the fake data provided in your post to keep things consistent. Note how I used dummies for states *and* periods, which is algebraically equivalent to estimation in deviations from means. The results should be equivalent to `reg1` in your post.

```
# Equivalent to reg1
# Includes state and period fixed effects

summary(mod_1 <- lm(y ~ as.factor(state) + as.factor(period) + x, data = df))

... (omitted)

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)          5.6159     3.1810   1.765    0.105
as.factor(state)2   -0.3492     2.2794  -0.153    0.881
as.factor(state)3    0.1619     2.2401   0.072    0.944
as.factor(state)4    1.0254     2.2116   0.464    0.652
as.factor(period)2   0.7500     2.4469   0.307    0.765
as.factor(period)3  -0.6071     3.0323  -0.200    0.845
as.factor(period)4   2.7024     2.5187   1.073    0.306
as.factor(period)5   1.3770     2.9192   0.472    0.646
x                   -0.9365     0.7960  -1.177    0.264
```

The estimate on `x` is equivalent to the estimate using the `plm()` function. Now let's introduce region fixed effects, which is equivalent to what you did in `reg2`.

```
# Equivalent to reg2
# The state fixed effects fully absorb the region effects

summary(mod_2 <- lm(y ~ as.factor(state) + as.factor(region) + as.factor(period) + x, data = df))

... (omitted)

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)          5.6159     3.1810   1.765    0.105
as.factor(state)2   -0.3492     2.2794  -0.153    0.881
as.factor(state)3    0.1619     2.2401   0.072    0.944
as.factor(state)4    1.0254     2.2116   0.464    0.652
as.factor(region)B       NA         NA      NA       NA
as.factor(period)2   0.7500     2.4469   0.307    0.765
as.factor(period)3  -0.6071     3.0323  -0.200    0.845
as.factor(period)4   2.7024     2.5187   1.073    0.306
as.factor(period)5   1.3770     2.9192   0.472    0.646
x                   -0.9365     0.7960  -1.177    0.264
```

The `lm()` function drops the region effects explicitly; they are absorbed by the state fixed effects (i.e., the state dummies). Note how it doesn't affect the point estimates. The `plm()` function, on the other hand, 'sweeps out' (i.e., 'differences out') all time-constant attributes of the state using the *within-transformation* (think about it as a deviation from a within-state time mean), hence why the region effects don't even appear in your output. This is why the results from `reg1` and `reg2` are equivalent. Again, the state fixed effects already adjust for the regional differences across states.

As a last word, if all you want to do is break the collinearity, then try dropping one *additional* state effect. Software will do this for you if you put the region effects *before* the state effects in your model formula.

```
# Note the ordering of the fixed effects!

summary(mod_3 <- lm(y ~ as.factor(region) + as.factor(state) + as.factor(period) + x, data = df))

... (omitted)

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)          5.6159     3.1810   1.765    0.105
as.factor(region)B   1.0254     2.2116   0.464    0.652
as.factor(state)2   -0.3492     2.2794  -0.153    0.881
as.factor(state)3   -0.8635     2.3289  -0.371    0.718
as.factor(state)4        NA         NA      NA       NA
as.factor(period)2   0.7500     2.4469   0.307    0.765
as.factor(period)3  -0.6071     3.0323  -0.200    0.845
as.factor(period)4   2.7024     2.5187   1.073    0.306
as.factor(period)5   1.3770     2.9192   0.472    0.646
x                   -0.9365     0.7960  -1.177    0.264
```

What's changed? Well, we estimated the region effects at the expense of losing one *additional* state. But note how the effect for region `B` offers no new information. In fact, the estimate for region `B` is equal to the coefficient on state `4` in the model *ignoring* the region effects entirely.

It's also worth noting that this doesn't even affect your estimate of `x`, which I presume is the principal variable of interest. In short, you should think about what variation you're trying to exploit. Maybe a region-by-year effect is something worth exploring.

In sum, the first model you estimated is already doing a lot of work for you. It removes all time-constant, state-specific heterogeneity. And, as already noted, a state's geographic region is a *fixed* attribute of that state.

Comment: Is it a good option to make a time * region effect?

Comment: What is “time”? Is it your “period” variable?

Comment: Yep, the period one

Comment: A region-by-year (i.e., `as.factor(region)*as.factor(period`)) effect is estimable and makes sense. I would estimate `x` with and without the region times year effects to see how they differ, if at all.

Comment: Hi, Thomas, I am still confused. In this way, if I use `as.factor(region)*as.factor(period)`, then I have (n-1)*(t-1) dummies, which makes the number of coefficients to estimate super large. Is it really reasonable?

Comment: It's doable with a state level panel. Say you have 50 states observed over 10 years, where $N \times T = 500$. Now say you have 5 regions. A region-by-year effect will return all combinations of region *and* year, for a total of 50 region-year effects. It's demanding of your data especially with a small number of U.S. states, but it won't chew up all your degrees of freedom.